# Verifying my one tailed setup for single sample hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, python, scipy

I have the following working code for 5% significance level:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp
import numpy as np
x =  [21.5, 24.5, 18.5, 17.2, 14.5, 23.2, 22.1, 20.5, 19.4, 18.1, 24.1, 18.5]
tscore, pvalue = ttest_1samp(x, popmean=-10)
print(np.mean(x))
print("t Statistic: ", tscore)
print("P Value: ", pvalue/2)

if (pvalue/2 < 0.05) and (tscore < 0):
    print("null H0: x̅ < µ accepted; alternative H1 : x̅ > µ rejected")

if (pvalue/2 > 0.05) and (tscore < 0):
    print("null H0: x̅ < µ rejected; alternative H1 : x̅ > µ accepted")

if (pvalue/2 < 0.05) and (tscore > 0):
    print("null H0: x̅ > µ accepted; alternative H1 : x̅ < µ rejected")

if (pvalue/2 > 0.05) and (tscore > 0):
    print("null H0: x̅ > µ rejected; alternative H1 : x̅ < µ accepted")
```

I am pretty sure about the code and null statements above. But I want to make sure that I am framing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusions should be as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp
import numpy as np
x = [21.5, 24.5, 18.5, 17.2, 14.5, 23.2, 22.1, 20.5, 19.4, 18.1, 24.1, 18.5]
tscore, pvalue = ttest_1samp(x, popmean=-10)
print(np.mean(x))
print("t Statistic: ", tscore)
print("P Value: ", pvalue/2)

if pvalue/2 < 0.05 and tscore < 0:
    print("null H0: x̅ = µ rejected; alternative H1 : x̅ < µ accepted")

if (pvalue/2 > 0.05) and (tscore < 0):
    print("null H0: x̅ = µ not rejected; alternative H1 : x̅ < µ not accepted")

if (pvalue/2 < 0.05) and (tscore > 0):
    print("null H0: x̅ = µ rejected; alternative H1 : x̅ > µ accepted")

if (pvalue/2 > 0.05) and (tscore > 0):
    print("null H0: x̅ = µ not rejected; alternative H1 : x̅ > µ not accepted")
```

When the p-value is *below the chosen significance level*, the null hypothesis ($H_0$) is *always rejected*.

One remark regarding the terminology: the null hypothesis is never "accepted", we either "reject it in favour of the alternative hypothesis" (when p-value < significance level) or "fail to reject it" (when p-value > significance level).

On a side note, in the most recent version of scipy (1.6.0) you can carry out a one-sided test directly with [ttest_1samp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html) by specifying either `ttest_1samp(x, popmean=-10, alternative='less')` or `ttest_1samp(x, popmean=-10, alternative='greater')`.

Comment: If you are doing 1 tail test then can you still define null H0 as x̅ = µ ?

Comment: Yes, the null hypothesis is the same for [one-tailed and two-tailed tests](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-the-differences-between-one-tailed-and-two-tailed-tests/); only the alternative hypothesis differs.

Comment: What does this mean? "null H0: x̅ = µ not rejected; alternative H1 : x̅ > µ not accepted"

Comment: It means that because the p-value is > 0.05, there is not enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis, so all you can say is that $H_0$ is _plausible_. Bear in mind that $H_0$ is the "devil's advocate" position and that hypothesis testing is usually used to prove that $H_0$ is **false** (e.g. in a clinical trial $H_0$ = the drug has no effect and you want to disprove this). If you cannot reject $H_0$, it does _not_ mean that you accept it, it simply means that $H_0$ is possible. You can read more about it [here](https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/failing-reject-null-hypothesis/).